# Having trouble in python 3.0 with this code

Tags: python, if-statement

I've been having trouble with this little program, it skips over the if == "otc": part completely, I've tried stuff to fix it but I just can't get it to work.

```
print("Hello, what is your name?")
name = input()
if name == "OTC":
     print("get out otc!")  
elif(): 
     print("Hello! " + name
```

Comment: That's not valid code. Also, is the `elif` with the empty tuple really necessary? That said, why 3.0? 3.5 is out already, containing lots of improvements, so upgrade!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if input has `otc` you can convert it into uppercase and check but if you want case sensitivity don't use upper()

**Modification:**

```
name = input("Hello, what is your name?")

if name.upper() == "OTC":

    print("get out otc!")

else:

    print("Hello! " + name)
```

**output:**

```
Hello, what is your name?"otc"
get out otc!


Hello, what is your name?"barny"
Hello! barny
```

**Changes in your code:**

There is no need for print since the same thing can be done using `input` function

There is no need for `elif` since there is only one condition check so use `else`

`elif` is a statement and not a function so remove the `()`

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to python, but this helped!

Comment: @CPPBro happy to help